# Talk pages (or feedback forms) at Ubuntu wikis

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

We don’t see either (or any form of per-page feedback) at wiki.ubuntu.com and community.ubuntu.com. Where should a (prospective) author go to coordinate their edits with other authors?

Comment: IRC or mailing lists, most probably.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about a site not under control of the StackExchange network and available on http://community.ubuntu.com/community-structure/

Comment: @Fabby: a ridiculous motivation. Are we at a meta site to discuss “sites under control of the StackExchange network”? ☺ This is a legitimate Ubuntu support question.

Comment: @Fabby:  Ī̲ don’t know anything about feuds with community.ubuntu.com, although may remove references to that one site on strong insistence. Anyway, **wiki.ubuntu.com** is an official Ubuntu resource, guy.

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes very much sense.. They coordinate however they want. Email, IRC, in person, over the phone, Google hangouts, whatever.

Comment: @Seth: Ī̲ made the question more precise.

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu Documentation team uses the [Ubuntu-doc](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-doc) mailing list and the IRC channel #ubuntu-doc on irc.freenode.net to communicate and coordinate where necessary. More information is laid out on [the contribute page for the documentation team.](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/documentation/)

Comment: That’s something useful, at last. Going to check whether guys from ubuntu-doc are collaborative, before upvoting.